# Can't update one value in datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have an edit form for values in datagridview. The problem is with **update** code. The whole code ***updated***:

```
int value = int.Parse(label13.Text); // ID
            string txtbox2 = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            string txtbox1 = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            try
            {
                var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_name='" + txtbox1 + "' AND g_surname = '"+txtbox2+"'  where ID =@id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

When the update sql command contains just one value to update - it works (example) :

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_name='" + textBox1.Text + "' where ID =@id";
```

[image]
The values not updating at all. But message box shows that everything was done.
Just changes name to "0".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use `AND` that way, replace it with a comma. And then parameterize all variables, not just id.

Comment: @Crowcoder okay, will try it right now

Comment: @Crowcoder updated the code, still doesn't work. The value of name changes to "0"

Comment: @Crowcoder write as an answer, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update statement is invalid. Try this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_name='" + textBox1.Text + "', g_surname = '"+textBox2.Text+"'  where ID =@id";
```

While we're at it, you should be passing those textbox values as parameters also. Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: will try it now